# How to give latest database name in Shrink database sql script?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have used below script to shrink database. I know even if not best practice but have requirement to do shrink. Is there any way to get latest database name every time into the script to shrink. at the moment I am doing manually but need to do automatically. Please can anyone suggest.

```
USE [Sales_backup_2016_08_10_203001_7966467]
ALTER DATABASE [Sales_backup_2016_08_10_203001_7966467]
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
DBCC SHRINKFILE (Sales_Data)
GO
USE [Sales_backup_2016_08_10_203001_7966467]
DBCC SHRINKFILE (Sales_Log,0)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Sales_backup_2016_08_10_203001_7966467]
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
DBCC SHRINKFILE (Sales_Log,0)
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of methods you could use:

**Method A: [Dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**

This query, which is a little old and could be improved, writes the shrink statement to a variable.  The variable is then executed.

For brevity, I've not included the full shrink statement.  Edit the line that starts `+ 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(d.name)...`.

This query is best viewed in *Results to Text mode* (Ctrl + T), as it uses line breaks to make the content easier to read (for us humans).

```
    DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX)  = ''        -- The dynamic SQL is written to this var.

    -- Populate @Qry.
    SELECT  
        @Qry = @Qry 
            + 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '; ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + ' ...;'
            + CHAR(10) 
    FROM    
        sys.Databases d
    WHERE   
        d.[State] =0 
        AND LOWER(d.Name) <> 'tempdb'
    ;

/* Enable the first line to run.
 * Disable the bottom line, when you are happy with the script.
 */
-- EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @Qry
SELECT @Qry;
```

**Method B: [Maintencance Tasks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140255(v=sql.105).aspx)**

Integration Services includes a number of tasks for performing maintenance work.  One of these is the [Shrink Database Task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141819(v=sql.105).aspx).  SQL Server includes a [wizard](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189036(v=sql.105).aspx) that can help you write and schedule your job.

Both methods can be scheduled using the [SQL Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189237.aspx).

**EDIT**

Corrected query, which contained an undeclared variable.

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) for more on building a single string from multiple rows.  You will see the method used above is not current best practice (and maybe wasn't even when I first wrote this query many years ago).

Comment: Thanks. when I am executing execute sp_executesql @bkuscript showing error must declare bkuscript. so, I replaced bkuscript to qry then query executed with result command completed successfully. but the database did not shrink. Am I missing anything? please suggest.

Comment: Apologies!  Copy and paste fail.  I'll update the example.  You were right to change the var to Qry.  How long did the process take?  If you paste the contents of Qry into a separate window does it run correctly?

Comment: when I am executing the query in separate and same window showing as NULL. nothing displaying. do I need to change anything

Comment: Think I know what is happening here.  Any string + NULL = NULL (that's why the first line is `DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';`).  If you edit your question to include your version of my query I can help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks. here is the one I used.

Comment: DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX)  = ''  -- The dynamic SQL is written to this var.
-- Populate Qry.
    SELECT  top 1 Qry = Qry 
+ 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + 'alter database '+QUOTENAME(d.name) +' '+'SET RECOVERY SIMPLE'+' '+'DBCC SHRINKFILE (Sales_Data)'+' '+'GO'+' '+ 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) +' '+
+'DBCC SHRINKFILE (Sales_Log,0)'+' '+'GO'+' '+'alter database ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) +' '+'SET RECOVERY SIMPLE'+' '+'DBCC SHRINKFILE (Sales_Log,0)'+' '+'GO'--+' '+--+ CHAR(10) 
FROM sys.Databases d WHERE d.[State] =0 
        AND LOWER(d.Name) <> 'tempdb'
ORDER BY create_date DESC;

Comment: /* Enable the first line to run.
 * Disable the bottom line, when you are happy with the script.
 */
EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @Qry 
--SELECT @Qry;

Comment: getting error message as below Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Comment: I am trying to post @ symbol in the replies but it is not allowing me to post @. but in the query I used @ symbol. please help me to sort out error message

Comment: The problem is with the [GO commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  From the docs *A Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a GO command*.  You can either a) remove GO or b) ensure they are written to a separate line.

Comment: Actually first I tried with separate line. after getting error I changed to single line.

Comment: I suspect that ExecuteSQL flattens strings, which is why added line breaks did not work.  Glad you got it up and running.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This Statement might help you

`SELECT TOP 1 NAME FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE name<>'tempdb' ORDER BY create_date DESC`

Comment: Thanks. This gives the latest database name. how can I include this statement into shrink db script which I added in ticket. please suggest. I mean how can I use the latest database name next to USE which I got from your select query that you posted.